# RESTful API - Custom Application - C#, Java, php?

Tags: api, rest

This is really basic.I  want to implement a RESTful web API.

Now I know you can write custom applications and scripts to integrate with the API.

What I need to know:

- In what languages can you write this API? C#, Java, php?
- When building/programming a program that implements this API, is this the client and the software that issued the API the server? (eg. Dropbox would be the server and the custom app that integrates with the Dropbox API is the Client?

Thank you.

Comment: JQuery is not a language. You can build a REST API in  almost any programming language known to mankind.

Comment: thank you Tom. quite direct and meaningful answer

Comment: About as meaningful as the question. You CAN write a RESTful web service (or a service client) in Java, C#, php, Ruby, Python, JavaScript, C++, Perl, Clojure, Scala, Groovy and dozens of other languages. I literally answered your first question right there. If you want to know which language to choose and why, you'll have to provide more details concerning your use case. This site is meant for specific programming questions, not for general research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A REST API can be built in any programming language that allows you to handle HTTP requests (or can be attached to a Web server as a handler for requests). The two methods I've been using:

1. Stand-alone Windows service implementing a REST service using WCF
2. WEB server Apache + PHP

You are correct about the terminology. A program consuming a service is called the client, a program providing a service is called the server (while actually in the PHP approach, Apache would be the server as it is taking the request and having the script handle it).

Additional nitpicking: JQuery is not a language, but a framework to help you use some JavaScript features more easily.

---

On your comment *Recap*:

Close :-) The Client transfers JSON/XML/whatever to a server using HTTP requests. The Client can be written in any language that can perform HTTP requests.

On the server side, there needs to be some application that handles the HTTP requests (service), also written in any language, as long as it "speaks" HTTP.

The API is the *definition* of which operations are possible, for example, adding user accounts, getting the current time, etc. (this is what you define - what do you want your service to do?).

The JSON/XML/whatever that you transfer is the workload, the parameters for the API call. For example, if you want to add a new user to your system, the workload could be the new user name, the real name, the eMail address and some other details about the user. If the API call returns the current server time, you might not need any parameters at all, but you get back JSON/XML/whatever from the service.

The actual *call* being made is determined by the URL you call. For example, the URL for adding a user could be `http://localhost/myrestservice/adduser` and you'd perform a POST request against that URL with the required workload. For the time example, the URL could be `http://localhost/myrestservice/getservertime` and you'd perform a GET request against that URL.

I suggest that you read about how REST services actually work before you start, as I see some question marks on your face ;-)

Short:

API = available operations (=> URLs)
Parameters to API calls = JSON/XML/Plain Text/whatever
Client = calls the service through HTTP
Service = handles the calls, replies to client in response to HTTP requests

Comment: thank you Thorsten. THe custom application you use to implement this RESTful Web API, can it also be written in any language?

Comment: Well, my answer to that is "Yes, but it's easier in some languages than in others". You see, a REST service is basically a HTTP server handling GET, POST, DELETE, etc. requests. C#/WCF to all that for you, if you want to use C++ for example, you'd have to implement your own HTTP server. If you use PHP/Perl/Python/Ruby/..., Apache or IIS may your HTTP servers.

Comment: OK I see.thanks. Recap: So if I understand this correctly, you have a custom application(client), written in any language, that transfers HTTP requests in XML/JSON format to a REST Web API, which is written in any language - This REST Web API is a service on the server application(example: Dropbox). So the API itself is not the XML/JSON requests being made right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a php programmer and familiar with Codeigniter framework then go here : [Working with RESTful Services in CodeIgniter](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/?search_index=2).

visit also : [Rest Tutorial](http://rest.elkstein.org/)

Answer (score 0):

As most of the people stated already, you can do this in just about any language.

Might I suggest that you look into NodeJS? If so, check out Restify: http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/

There's a nice community behind NodeJS and I think it's quite open to newcomers. Just try not to pick up bad habits from JavaScript pitfalls. If you're new to programming, I'd suggest reading some intro book.

good luck!

Comment: thank you Lander. THe custom application you use to implement this RESTful Web API, can it also be written in any language?

Comment: NodeJS is JavaScript. There are some hack to bind with other languages in NodeJS, but I would advise against it.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should begin with learning **what** is a RESTful API.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer
- http://www.restapitutorial.com/
- http://rest.elkstein.org/

> In what languages can you write this API? C#, Java, php, jQuery?

You can write an API in any language. What can help is the framework you'd be using. JQuery is not a language, but a framework for integrating Javascript application in every web browser, so it won't help.

I'd advice you to use a microframework to write your first RESTful API, because they usually are easy to use and help focus on the important (bottle/flask in python, express in javascript, silex in php, spark in java or nina in C#)

> When building/programming a program that implements this API, is this the client and the software that issued the API the server? (eg. Dropbox would be the server and the custom app that integrates with the Dropbox API is the Client?

You're right, the server is providing you the service, hence the API. The client is user to that API, and implementing it into something useful.

Comment: thank you, appreciate your answer. THe custom application you use to implement this RESTful Web API, can it also be written in any language?